# Camera switch between First and third person. Showing error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I am trying to make a camera switch between first person and third person. Here is the code:

```
[SerializeField]
private Camera ThirdPersonCam;
private KeyCode switchKey;

//Assingables
public Transform playerCam;
public Transform orientation;

private void Update()
{
    MyInput();
    Look();

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(switchKey))
    {
        playerCam.enabled = !playerCam.enabled;
        ThirdPersonCam.enabled = !ThirdPersonCam.enabled;
    }
}
```

However, in this line `playerCam.enabled = !playerCam.enabled;`, it shows this error:

```
'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'enabled' and no accessible extension method 'enabled' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

But in the line beneath it, it doesn’t show. I am confused why is it happening and `enabled` is a definition for the `Transform`. Can someone help me out to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: It is correct. Transforms dont have an enabled property. The game objects do. Either keep a reference nod the gameobject or adjust your code to tell the gameobjeect to enable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says, Transform doesn’t have a definition `enabled`. You should change the variable type from `Transform` to `Camera` as you are trying to access the camera not the position.

So instead of this,

```
private Transform playerCam;
```

Change it to this;

```
private Camera playerCam;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "enable" for Transform in the documentation as far as I can tell: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html
If you want to invert the active status (aka enable) from having a reference to their transform, use:

```
playerCam.gameObject.SetActive(!playerCam.gameObject.activeSelf)
```

Since this is a bit convoluted, it often makes sense to keep references to the game objects themselves instead of their transform.

Answer (score 0):

you've defined the global/serializable playerCam to be of type transform so you cannot enable/disable them.
Change the types to Camera and it should be fine

```
[SerializeField]
private Camera ThirdPersonCam;
private KeyCode switchKey;

//Assingables
public Camera playerCam;
public Transform orientation;
```